# Subtracting in loops associated with variables

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a loop that keeps subtracting from the initial amount of each item until the amount is less than the price of an item. It is also supposed to show the last item purchased before the amount was less than the price of an item. Cars cost $310,000, rings cost $12,500, Diamonds cost $150,000 and chocolate costs $51. The items are in a file on my computer, and the following is an example of what it should look like.

Sample Input:

```
350000
Car
Ring
Diamond
Car
Chocolate
Diamond
```

Sample Output:

```
Ring
$27, 500 left
```

For some reason, the value I get the wrong value when I subtract, but I can't figure out why. I've declared the prices for each item and checked multiple times to make sure they are correct, and I've checked my code, but I still don't know why I get the wrong output.

```
Private Sub btnS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnS.Click
    Dim inFile As StreamReader = New StreamReader("serena.txt")
    'Declare the varibles
    Dim variableName As String
    ' the current items from the file
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim price As Integer
    amount = Val(inFile.ReadLine())
    Do
        'read in the words
        variableName = inFile.ReadLine()
        'determine each item's price
        If variableName = "car" Then price = 310000
        If variableName = "ring" Then price = 12500
        If variableName = "diamond" Then price = 150000
        If amount >= price Then amount = amount - price
    Loop Until amount < price

    'output the results
    Me.lblOutput.Text = variableName & _
        vbNewLine & "Serena has " & Format(amount, "currency") & " left"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the **COMMENTS** I've placed into the code below:

```
Private Sub btnS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnS.Click
    Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "serena.txt")

    Dim inFile As New StreamReader(fileName)

    Dim itemToPurchase As String
    Dim lastThingBought As String = "{ Nothing Bought }" ' what if they can't afford anything?
    Dim balance As Integer
    Dim price As Integer
    Dim somethingBought As Boolean

    balance = Val(inFile.ReadLine())
    Do
        somethingBought = False ' we don't know yet if we can purchase the next item
        'read in the words
        itemToPurchase = inFile.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim() ' make sure it has no spaces and is lowercase to match below
        'determine each item's price
        Select Case itemToPurchase
            Case "car"
                price = 310000

            Case "ring"
                price = 12500

            Case "diamond"
                price = 150000

            Case "chocolate" ' FYI: you were missing chocolate in your code
                price = 51

            Case Else ' it could happen!
                MessageBox.Show(itemToPurchase, "Unknown Item!")
                lblOutput.Text = "Error in file"
                Exit Sub

        End Select
        If balance >= price Then
            somethingBought = True
            balance = balance - price
            ' we need to store the last thing purchased,
            ' because "itemToPurchase" gets replaced with the thing you couldn't afford
            lastThingBought = itemToPurchase
        End If
        ' Need to check for the end of file being reached...
        ' ...they may purchase everything in the file and still have money left!
    Loop While Not inFile.EndOfStream AndAlso somethingBought

    'output the results
    Me.lblOutput.Text = lastThingBought &
        vbNewLine & "Serena has " & Format(balance, "currency") & " left"
End Sub
```